# remove all negative integers from a list of integer

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I need to remove all the negative values from a list of integers.

```
Dim cells As List(Of Integer) = GridView1.GetSelectedRows().ToList()
```

`cells` returns a list of rows getting from the devexpress grid view. But the filter/group option will return negative integers... How can I either remove those negative values from cells or prevent them from getting in to cells?

Comment: You may also want not to allow the user to select grouped rows. If so, this article describes how to do this: [How to prevent group rows from being selected in multi-select mode](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A381)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
    Dim NumberOfElements As Integer = cells.Count - 1
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i <= NumberOfElements
        If cells(i) < 0 Then
            cells.RemoveAt(i)
            NumberOfElements = NumberOfElements - 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End While
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     Dim postiveCells As List(Of Integer) = cells.[Where](Function(x) x > 0).ToList()
> ```

I think I find a way to put a where clause in the vb.net 
Thank you for the hint